# Error when extending a template abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have this code for a Node based Queue implementation and I'm supposed to extends an abstract class called QueueInterface.

```
template<typename T>
struct QueueInterface {
    public:
    virtual ~QueueInterface(){};
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual void enqueue(const T value) = 0;
    virtual void dequeue() throw(PreconditionViolationException) = 0;
    virtual T peekFront() const throw(PreconditionViolationException) = 0;
};    

template<typename T>
struct Queue : QueueInterface {
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void enqueue(const T value);
    void dequeue() throw(PreconditionViolationException);
    T peekFront() const throw(PreconditionViolationException);

private:
    Node<T>* front;
    Node<T>* back;
};
```

I keep getting a `expected class name before '{' token` error even though I included the QueueInterface header file. Why is this happening?

Comment: Most likely there is a typo in `Node.h` or `QueueInterface.h`.

Comment: There isn't. I checked. Also why would a typo in `Node.h` throw that error

Comment: This is going to be a guess fest without knowing the content of the other files. Can you reduce them all as much as possible while still getting the error? TIA (P.S: my money is on a missing ; at the end of a class declaration)

Comment: Thing is I've tried thinning down the interface class as much as possible. Like even with no method declarations in it, the compiler still throws the error. No missing ; at the end of class either...

Comment: @pyro97 Because it is the last include file.  If there is a typo in it then it comes into this file.

Comment: Can you show `QueueInterface.h`?

Comment: My guess here is circular inclusion. But that's a guess. If you don't want us to guess, give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could test easily and reproduce your error.

Comment: P.S: IME header guards usually go before the includes, not after.

Answer (score 1):

`QueueInterface` is not a class. You can inherit from something that is not a struct or a class. This thing is what is called a *templated class*. You can recognize templates with the `template<...>` just before the templated class. You must specify a type so the compiler can create a class of that type.

In your case, you are trying to create a struct that is also a template. By looking at the overrides of the methods of your base classes, I guess you are trying to do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Queue : QueueInterface<T> { 
    //   notice that there ---^--- you are sending the required parameter

    // defaulted members are good.
    Queue() = default;

    // override too.
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    void enqueue(const T value) override;
    void dequeue() throw(PreconditionViolationException) override;
    T peekFront() const throw(PreconditionViolationException) override;

private:
    Node<T>* front;
    Node<T>* back;
};
```